# C#: Getting Substring between two different Delimiters

Tags: c#, regex, split

I have problems splitting this Line. I want to get each String between "@VAR;" and "@ENDVAR;". So at the End, there should be a output of:

```
Variable=Speed;Value=Fast;
Variable=Fabricator;Value=Freescale;Op==;
```

Later I will separate each Substring, using ";" as a delimiter but that I guess wont be that hard. This is how a line looks like:

```
@VAR;Variable=Speed;Value=Fast;Op==;@ENDVAR;@VAR;Variable=Fabricator;Value=Freescale;Op==;@ENDVAR;
```

I tried some split-options, but most of the time I just get an empty string. I also tried a Regex. But either the Regex was wrong or it wasnt suitable to my String. Probably its wrong, at school we learnt Regex different then its used in C#, so I was confused while implementing.

```
Regex.Match(t, @"/@VAR([a-z=a-z]*)/@ENDVAR")
```

**Edit:**

One small question: I am iterating over many lines like the one in the question. I use NoIdeas code on the line to get it in shape. The next step would be to print it as a Text-File. To print an Array I would have to loop over it. But in every iteration, when I get a new line, I overwrite the Array with the current splitted string. I put the Rest of my code in the question, would be nice if someone could help me.

```
string[] w ;
foreach (EA.Element theObjects in myPackageObject.Elements)
{
   theObjects.Type = "Object";
   foreach (EA.Element theElements in PackageHW.Elements)
   {
       if (theObjects.ClassfierID == theElements.ElementID)
       {
          t = theObjects.RunState;
          w = t.Replace("@ENDVAR;", "@VAR;").Replace("@VAR;", ";").Split(new string[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

          foreach (string s in w)
          {
             tw2.WriteLine(s);
          }
       }
   }
}
```

The piece with the foreach-loop is wrong pretty sure. I need something to print each splitted t. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's tw2? please add it's definition

Comment: ah sorry, its a Textwriter.

Comment: And by Text-File I mean, I need the outout for further data processing. The optimal output would be Speed = Fast; Fabricator = Freescale. More general the Variable.Value = Value.Value. After the @VAR and stuff is gone, I have to cut out the field with op== and then I have the ";" as a Delimiter, so that split wont be that hard to realise. I am pretty new to C#, so I have problems realising the stuff I want to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do it without regex using

```
str.Replace("@ENDVAR;", "@VAR;")
  .Split(new string[] { "@VAR;" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

and if you want to save time you can do:

```
str.Replace("@ENDVAR;", "@VAR;")
  .Replace("@VAR;", ";")
  .Split(new string[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: Sorry, got distracted. String.Split is never the answer.

Comment: @Gusdor what? you can say you don't like it but that's only an opinion... to say it's never the answer you need to back it up with some facts...

Comment: @gusdor string.split is better than regex?

Comment: Too much can go wrong with String.Split. Regex is more explicit, can capture more complex patterns and produces cleaner code at negligible performance cost.

Comment: @gusdor Now you have two problems.

Comment: @Gusdor regex in not understandable as split and be a real annoying when trying to debug. but that's opinion. i also did not state you have to use split. i gave an answer...

Comment: @mbeckish absolutely, regex aren't the solution to all problems. You dont validate numeric input with it. You can, but it is error prone. Similarly, String.Split is not the solution to all problems. Its great for parsing CSV files. It is not so great for matching strings with non-uniform delimiting. Note that the first code example in this very answer pre-processes the input before splitting. Why? You have just created an extra string for each split/replace and a further string for every occurrence of @ENDVAR; Grim! It also iterates over a string of arbitrary length TWICE.

Comment: In conclusion, regex is, by definition, better at parsing strings in c# than string.split. If you can't read it. Learn it. It is a highly portable skill with many applications. If you still struggle, grab an excellent regex creation tool like RegexBuddy. I used RegexBuddy to diagnose this issue in seconds.

Comment: @Gusdor *String.Split [is] great for parsing CSV files.* Hell, no. It's absolutely the wrong tool for that.

Comment: @DominicKexel Elaborate, sir. You have aroused my interest.

Comment: If you're going to replace down to the character, use the character overload? `Split(new char[] { ';' }`

Comment: @Gusdor it's not a good solution for parsing CSV, because CSV has delimiters that need to be considered, e.g. `Name,"Boston, MA",11111` how would you do that using string.split?

Comment: This version could also be cleaned up some, i.e. too much replacing. `.Split(new string[] { "@VAR;", "@ENDVAR;" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);` But unlike most of regex options, these string splits have the problem of including stuff between end and begin delimiters. Perhaps eschew the removeemptyentries, and only use even entries.

Comment: @McKay If a field starts with a quote but does not end with a quote, merge it with the next one. That is not desirable but what other logic would you apply?

Comment: @Gusdor my point is, you should be using a specialized library for CSV. And if you're making a specialized library, analyze character by character (indexof...), and test the crap out of it.

Comment: when you combine split with linq you get a lot of flexibility in what you can do.

Comment: @McKay analyse character by character? If only there was a scripting language which did that...

Comment: Thank you for your input guys, you had fun discussing this :D I want to print a txt-file with the output, but using textwriter tw; tw.Write(w). w = "NoIdeasSolution". But I just get "System.String[]" as Output.

Comment: @Alika87 perform a foreach loop upon the string[] and call TextWriter.WriteLine(eachItem) on each item. Regex really polarises the party :D Glad you enjoyed it.

Comment: @Gusdor If you're building a library for CSV parsing, you should totally care about performance more than regex will give you.

Comment: Thanks gusdor and to be honest, I didnt enjoyed it, had to test every posted solution :D

Comment: One small question: I am iterating over many lines like the one in the question. I use NoIdeas code on the line to get it in shape. The next step would be to print it as a Text-File. To print an Array I would have to loop over it. But in every iteration, when I get a new line, I overwrite the Array with the current splitted string. I put the Rest of my code in the question, would be nice if someone could help me.

Comment: @Alika87 i would suggest you put a new question for that, so you'll get freash answers. if you prefer not to, i would try to help, but i need you to edit the question and ask it in a clearer fashion. what do you mean "print it as a Text-File"? do you want to create a file?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a look ahead assertion here.

```
@VAR;(.*?)(?=@ENDVAR)
```

If your string never consists of whitespace between `@VAR;` and `@ENDVAR;` you could use the below line, this will not match empty instances of your lines.

```
@VAR;([^\s]+)(?=@ENDVAR)
```

See this [demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/vG8zB8)

Comment: the asterisk use here is better than my answer. It will cover instances where there is no content in a line.

Comment: @VAR;([^\s]+)(?=@ENDVAR) for the \s my compiler tells my unknown escapesequenz??

Comment: Try using `@VAR;([^\\s]+)(?=@ENDVAR)` or just use `@VAR;([^ ]+)(?=@ENDVAR)`

Answer (score 2):

Answer using raw string manipulation.

```
IEnumerable<string> StuffFoundInside(string biggerString)
{
    var closeDelimeterIndex = 0;
    do
    {
        int openDelimeterIndex = biggerString.IndexOf("@VAR;", startingIndex);
        if (openDelimeterIndex != -1)
        {
            closeDelimeterIndex = biggerString.IndexOf("@ENDVAR;", openDelimeterIndex);
            if (closeDelimiterIndex != -1)
            {
                yield return biggerString.Substring(openDelimeterIndex, closeDelimeterIndex - openDelimiterIndex);
            }
        }    
    } while (closeDelimeterIndex != -1);
}
```

Making a list and adding each item to the list then returning the list might be faster, depending on how the code using this code would work. This allows it to terminate early, but has the coroutine overhead.

Comment: Now you have 15 lines of problems :D

Comment: @Gusdor Oh, I wouldn't really use this in most code. I upvoted the string.split solution, though this one is going to run faster, and I'd use it if performance matters. It hasn't been tested. Pick your poison. I see 4 different kinds of poison that need to be considered: Break-early performance, list get all performance, ease of development, ease of maintenance. I think the string.split option is probably the best overall

Comment: This is my personal favorite. It has something for everyone and it will make junior engineers cry into their keyboards! It only creates one string per occurance as well. Kudos.

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex:

```
(?i)@VAR;(.+?)@ENDVAR;
```

Group 1 in each match will be your line content.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried some split-options, but most of the time I just get an empty string.

In this case the requirements seem to be simpler than you're stating.  Simply splitting and using linq will do your whole operation in one statement:

```
        string test = "@VAR;Variable=Speed;Value=Fast;Op==;@ENDVAR;@VAR;Variable=Fabricator;Value=Freescale;Op==;@ENDVAR;";

        List<List<string>> strings = (from s in test.Split(new string[]{"@VAR;",";@ENDVAR;"},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                                let s1 = s.Split(new char[]{';'},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList<string>()
                                select (s1)).ToList<List<string>>();
```

the outpout is:

```
?strings[0]
Count = 3
    [0]: "Variable=Speed"
    [1]: "Value=Fast"
    [2]: "Op=="
?strings[1]
Count = 3
    [0]: "Variable=Fabricator"
    [1]: "Value=Freescale"
    [2]: "Op=="
```

To write the data to a file something like this will work:

```
        foreach (List<string> s in strings)
        {
            System.IO.File.AppendAllLines("textfile1.txt", s);
        }
```

Comment: You should probably use `StartsWith` over contains here.

Answer (score 1):

(If you don't like regexs)

Code:

```
var s = "@VAR;Variable=Speed;Value=Fast;Op==;@ENDVAR;@VAR;Variable=Fabricator;Value=Freescale;Op==;@ENDVAR;";
var tokens = s.Split(new String [] {"@ENDVAR;@VAR;"}, StringSplitOptions.None);

foreach (var t in tokens)
{
  var st = t.Replace("@VAR;", "").Replace("@ENDVAR;", "");
  Console.WriteLine(st);
}
```

Output:

```
Variable=Speed;Value=Fast;Op==;
Variable=Fabricator;Value=Freescale;Op==;
```

Comment: But what if there was a character between the endvar and the next begin var?

Comment: @McKay It won't work :) I assumed OP will always have strings like the one he wrote in the question.

Comment: Yeah, that *might* be a safe assumption.

Comment: there wont be another char between the end and the begin. Its autogenerated and will have always the same format.

Answer (score 1):

`Regex.Split` works well but yields empty entries that have to be removed as shown here:

```
string[] result = Regex.Split(input, @"@\w+;")
    .Where(s => s != "")
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: System.String[] thats the output I get when printing result.

Comment: The answer by @NoIdeaForName fixes that issue.

Comment: @Alika87: `foreach (string s in result) Console.WriteLine(s);`